# What changes should i made so that i can use `useDispatch` in action of react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

The question is it possible to `useDispatch` in loader (loginAction)?

I am trying to learn **react-redux/toolkit** and also trying to learn new **react-router-dom features**.

In **react-router-dom** tutorial. They are using something call `createBrowserRouter`  from **react-router-dom**

They got path, element, loader, errrorElement ...  and so on

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <MainLayout />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Dashboard />,
        loader: DashbaordLoader,
        errorElement: <Error />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <Items />,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
    action: loginAction
  },
]);
```

As you can see in the code the login have loginAction.

In the Login component , I have something like this. As you can see in the code. It is using formRef
to grab data from the from. But this thing is I can't use `useDispatch` and `useNavigate` from `redux/toolkit` in the loginAction

```
export async function loginAction({ request }: any) {
  const data = await request.formData();
  return data;
}
 
const Login = () => {
  const formRef = useRef<ElementRef<"form">>(null);
 
      <Form ref={formRef} method="post" action="/login" >
                <label >Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="Enter your email"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  id="password"
                  placeholder="Enter your password"
                />
              </div>
 
              <div>
                <Link to="/forget">
                  Forgot password
                </Link>
              </div>
 
              <button>
                Sign In
              </button>
            </Form>
```

Comment: "The question is it possible to combine these features?" - Yes. What exactly are you trying to do though? Depending on what you want to do it may, or may not, make sense to do Redux "stuff" in the route loader. Route loaders are intended to fetch data for the routed component. Login actions might be better suited for route actions, or handled in the component directly. Can you [edit] to clarify what issue you are trying to overcome in better detail?

Comment: I got another question. Let say I decided to use `redux/toolkit` in my project. I can totally avoid using these features from `react-router-dom`, Example such as using`formRef` to handle the data coming from the Form. I can avoid it by manually using `useState` for each Input. If I were to do that I am writing bad code? or is that acceptable.

Comment: You can only use React hooks in React functions and custom hooks, and since route loaders/actions are neither you can't use the `useDispatch` hook. You *can* dispatch actions directly to a Redux store instance though, e.g. store.dispatch(.....)`.